# How to output an hash to table format in ruby

Tags: hash

I have an hash 
rows = [{"col1"=>"v1", "col2"=>"v2"}, {"col1"=>"v3", "col2"=>"v4"}] like

I want the output in table format using ruby

Could you please provide an answer?